# Duplicates of a document is visible on one username automatically

Tags: office-365, online

Duplicates of a document is visible on one username automatically in a document library. But user didn't visit the site. Every document has same content. I have checked there is no workflow is running.
So what could be the reason.?

For E.g.:-

```
Doc.Name  Modified   ModifiedBy
A.xlsx    2/20/2019  Mr.X
A1.xlsx   2/20/2019  Mr.X
A2.xlsx   2/20/2019  Mr.X
A3.xlsx   2/20/2019  Mr.X
............
```

Comment: Hello, Please shares more details like screenshot, what do you mean by one username? When you say visible, do you mean in all the views or in a particular view?

Comment: On one username means-->on "modified By" column username is mentioned.here only one view allitems.aspx. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it creating duplicate documents in library or just modified by field is changing for all documents?

Comment: Creating   "duplicate docs + modified by" also.

Comment: Does that user have any sync with one drive to the library?

Comment: Yes.That is "SYNC" issue only from onedrive.Thank you Arvi.